# Cambiar Imagen Background del Sistema Android

Tags: java, android

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es tener una aplicación donde exista un botón, cuando presione el botón quiero cambiar la **Imagen background del sistema android**.

Quiero cambiar esta imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He investigado como puedo hacer esto, pero lo unico es:

- Como cambiar la imagen de un ImageView.
- Como cambiar la imagen de fondo de una Aplicación.
- Como cambiar la imagen de un Activity ... y cosas asi.

Obviamente lo estoy buscando mal, Que puedo investigar para lograr mi objetivo ???

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase WallpaperManager:

```
Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set);
ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);

buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

y debes añadir a tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`  el permiso para realizar el cambio:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```